# Replacing Date Format in multiple Columns

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, notepad++, csv

I am trying to edit a CSV file in Notepad++.
I have about 500 lines of dates in a format that I need to change to a different format, so basically, in the CSV file in Notepad, the dates are shown as Aug 16,1995. I have changed to the correct format seperately (16-Aug-1995) in Excel. So how to I go about pasting the correct format from Excel into the 500 lines in Notepad?
I cant just paste it into the CSV as that will mess up the formatting of the names in the CSV file.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\b([a-z]{3}) (\d\d?),(\d{4})\b`
- Replace with: `$2-$1-$3`
- **UNCHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\b              # word boundary
([a-z]{3})      # group 1, 3 letters  (the month)
                # a space
(\d\d?)         # group 2, 1 or 2 digits  (the day)
,               # a comma
(\d{4})         # group 3, 4 digits  (the year)
\b              # word boundary
```

**Replacement:**

```
$2          # content of group 2, the day
-           # a hyphen
$1          # content of group 1, the month
-           # a hyphen
$3          # content of group 3, the year
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]